# Ударные слова в предложениях

Tags: орфоэпия, оформление-текста

Существует ли в русском языке правило, согласно которому слова в предложении выделяются на письме графическим ударением?
Например: "Всё, чтó встречалось ему в жизни, чрезвычайно сильно действовало на его восприимчивую натуру..."

Answer (score 2):

Конкретного правила, регулирующего выделение слов графическим ударением, нет. Однако ударение может ставиться по другим причинам. Например, в книге "Встреча с Пушкиным" все слова представлены с ударением. Книга предназначена иностранным студентам-нефилологам, завершившим начальный курс обучения русского языка.  Цель ударения – помочь правильно произносить слова.

Answer (score 2):

Правила нет и быть не может, потому что только автор решает, какое слово в предложении ударное.

(Потому мне и непонятна практика начитывать аудиокниги "с листа", без предварительного ознакомления с текстом.)

Такое ударение называется логическим.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И ещё немножко пояснений:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть и рекомендация (видимо, издателям) - об омографах, требующих графического ударения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]